# see memory left from within ReactNative app?

Tags: react-native, memory

Is there a way, that works, for checking how much RAM memory is left on the device. I only care about Android devices.

I tried react-native-vitals but I couldnt get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem with react-native-vitals.
Their documentation was wrong:

Documentation says:

```
Vitals.getMemory(memory => {
  console.log("memory:", memory, "");
});
```

But one should do:

```
Vitals.getMemory().then(memory => {
  console.log("memory:", memory, "");
});
```